# validar si un registro existe antes de insertar laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy intentando realizando un insert en una tabla con una relación de muchos a muchos.
Mi duda es hay si alguna forma de validar, si esa relación existe no la agregue nuevamente este es el código que uso pero no se si eloquent ya trae algo similar.

```
    // Conseguimos el objeto
$peli=Pelicula::where('fk_segmento', "1")
->where('fk_empresa', '1')
->first();

// Si existe
if(count($peli)>=1){
   //realizo el insert
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La otra respuesta da una buena idea, pero no es del todo correcta y por eso es que la sintaxis que funciona es la que pusiste en el comentario y no la de la respuesta como tal.

---

A continuación la explicación:

Este es el código del método `firstOrCreate()`, ubicado en https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L366

```
/**
 * Get the first record matching the attributes or create it.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 */
public function firstOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    if (! is_null($instance = $this->where($attributes)->first())) {
        return $instance;
    }

    return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes + $values), function ($instance) {
        $instance->save();
    });
}
```

Tal y como lo explica la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) y como se ve en el código, el primer array de parámetros son **los atributos con los cuales se realizará la búsqueda** en la base de datos, y el segundo array son **los valores adicionales con los cuales se creará el modelo** / registro en la base de datos, en caso que no se encuentre ningun registro que coincida con los atributos del primer array.

En ese orden de ideas,

```
Pelicula::firstOrCreate(['fk_segmento' => '1'], ['fk_empresa' => '1']);`
```

**NO FUNCIONA** porque le estás diciendo a Eloquent que busque un registro que tenga `fk_segmento = 1`, y si no lo encuentra, que lo cree junto con el valor `fk_empresa = 1`.

---

El código que pusiste en el comentario:

```
Pelicula::firstOrCreate(['fk_segmento' => '1', 'fk_empresa' => '1']);
```

le indica a Eloquent que busque un registro que tenga los valores `fk_segmento = 1` **Y** `fk_empresa = 1` (y que lo cree si no lo encuentra), lo cual concuerda con lo que planteas en el código de la pregunta:

```
...
where('fk_segmento', "1")
->where('fk_empresa', '1')
```

Comment: Que buena explicación y es totalmente acertada.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso podrías utilizar el `firstOrCreate`, éste método lo que hace es buscar un registro en la base de datos según los parámetros que le pases, si no encuentra ningún registro entonces lo crea

```
Pelicula::firstOrCreate(['fk_segmento' => '1'], ['fk_empresa' => '1']);
```

Comment: Me arrojo este error : `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: En este `firstorcreate` debes colocar todos los campos que se deben guardar en caso de que no exista el registro

Comment: si ya solucione ese error pero de igual manera no guarda así no existan los datos

Comment: No te sale algún mensaje o algo? es extraño que no te guarde si mandas todos los datos bien

Comment: Puedes mostrarme como mandaste los datos?

Comment: funciono pero de esta manera 
`Pelicula::firstOrCreate(['fk_segmento' => '1', 'fk_empresa' => '1']);`

Comment: Ah sí claro, sus también puedes mandar los valores del array, me alegra que te haya servido el firstorcreate, eloquent tiene un alcance inmenso!